# Как сделать поиск по словарю?

Tags: python-3.x

Надо сделать чтобы пользователь вводил цвет и на консоль выводилось есть ли эта переменная в словаре
Нужно чтобы при наличии переменной в словаре выполнялся if.

```
colors = {
    1: {'title': 'красный', 'value': COLOR_RED},
    2: {'title': 'оранжевый', 'value': COLOR_ORANGE},
    3: {'title': 'жёлтый', 'value': COLOR_YELLOW},
    4: {'title': 'зелёный', 'value': COLOR_GREEN},
    5: {'title': 'голубой', 'value': COLOR_CYAN},
    6: {'title': 'синий', 'value': COLOR_BLUE},
    7: {'title': 'фиолетовый', 'value': COLOR_PURPLE}

}

for number, title in colors.items():
    print(title['title'])
user_input = input('Выберите цвет:')


if user_input in colors:
    print('Входит')
else:
    print('Не входит')
```

Пробовал поиск по значениям - не выходит.

Comment: Что Вы вводите и что хотите получить в итоге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if any(user_input == v['title'] for _, v in colors.items()):
    ...
```

Comment: Вместо `items()` тогда уж лучше использовать `.values()` :)

Comment: @gil9red и правда. Часто допускаю эту ошибку.